# Getting around c++ strict-aliasing rules

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

I want to store a bounded number of items in a container. I don't want to use an array because I want to avoid unnecessary object constructor calls. I don't want to use `std::vector` because of the implicit `malloc` call (I want to minimize access to the heap for maximal cache coherence).

So I set out to define my own custom container, something like this:

```
template<typename T, size_t capacity> class my_array {
  private:
   char buffer[sizeof(T)*capacity];
   ...
  public:
   T& operator[](size_t i) { return *(T*)&buffer[i*sizeof(A)]; }
   ...
};
```

But when I try to actually use this container, I get compiler warnings about breaking strict-aliasing rules. I've read up on strict-aliasing, and I understand why compiler optimizations can cause the above code to break.

How do I get around this?

What's strange is that my compiler has no complaints about my custom `object_pool` class, which, among other things, I use for a custom allocator for my associative STL data structures. That class looks awfully similar to the above (uses a `char[]` and does a similar cast). I can't figure out what the difference between the two is.

Comment: Can't you just use `std::array`? Or `std::tr1::array` or `boost::array` of you don't have C++11 support?

Comment: I don't have c++11 support. Even if I did...another requirement I have is that I don't want to actually call the constructor of `T` immediately, for performance reasons. I should have mentioned this requirement, I will edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

use `std::array`
. . . . . . . . . . . . . !

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to use `std:array` then

```
char buffer[sizeof(T)*capacity];
```

should probably be

```
T buffer[capacity]
```

That's why templates support `typename`s in the first place.

Comment: Is there anyway to do that without incurring the call of `T`'s constructor?

Comment: No. That makes it much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::aligned_storage` if you don't want to initialize the objects as `std::array` requires. You're likely to hit an alignment issue, as your struct might be assigned to an odd address.

Aliasing with a `char` array to use it as storage should be fine, I'm not sure what your compiler is on about. Is that really a minimal testcase?

Comment: re "Aliasing with a char array to use it as storage should be fine". for the purely formal the char array here needs not be suitably aligned for T. it's not a dynamically allocated array. in practice, if the OP has a virtual function or something, then the array needs not be at the start of the struct, so even if the struct is suitably aligned the array needs not be.

Comment: If you add an instantiation of `my_array<int,4>` and then use the `[]` operator, then yes, it is a minimal testcase. I too am confused, because I thought there was an exception for `char`.

Comment: Unfortunately, don't have c++11 support, so can't use std::aligned_storage.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a mysterious solution by comparing precisely to the `object_pool` class I alluded to in my original post.

I replaced

```
T& operator[](size_t i) { return *(T*)&buffer[i*sizeof(A)]; }
```

with

```
T* operator[](size_t i) {
  if (...) {
    return (T*)&buffer[i*sizeof(A)];
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

where the `...` is any predicate that I know will always evaluate to `true`, but which the compiler is not smart enough to realize will always evaluate to `true`.

I'd be curious if anyone can explain exactly what is going through the compiler's head here. I'm using gcc 4.4.3.